# Как получить текст из textview, на который нажал пользователь

Tags: java, android, android-textview, gettext

У меня есть несколько textview, которые создаются программно в неком layout. Пользователь может кликнуть по любому из них. Клик реализован с помощью метода ontouch. Вопрос в том, как можно извлечь текст, который содержится в textview, на которое кликнул пользователь, чтобы затем поместить этот текст в переменную типа String.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onTouch` имеет `View v` в качестве аргумента. Это ссылка на нажатый элемент разметки. Вам надо просто скастовать его к типу `TextView` и уже из него, методом `getText()` получить текст.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) v;
    String textFromTV = tv.getText().toString();
    return true;
}
```